# Problem with JMeter and HTTP Proxy Server with SSL

Tags: jmeter

We are using JMeter 2.4 and are trying to use the HTTP Proxy Server to capture a test plan.

"Attempt HTTPS spoofing" is not ticked.

The error we get in the JMeter log is:

2010/08/02 14:46:02 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: **Problem with SSL certificate? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert:**
Connection closed by remote host 
2010/08/02 14:46:02 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler: Error Response Code: 404
2010/08/02 14:46:02 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler: Error Response Code: 404
2010/08/02 14:46:02 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy:  java.net.SocketException:   Connection closed by remote host
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.writeToClient(Proxy.java:443)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:264)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You must remove in your browser the auto-signed certificat in relation with your website, and restart a record session with JMeter 2.4. In this new session, accept the JMeter's dummy cert.

(in Firefox : Options > Advanced > Encryption > View Certificates ==> Certificat Manager > Servers > choose website cert and Delete...)

Milamber

Answer (score 3):

From http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server

> When recording HTTPS, the JMeter proxy
>   server uses a dummy certificate to
>   enable it to accept the SSL connection
>   from the browser. This certificate is
>   not one of the certificates that
>   browsers normally trust, and will not
>   be for the correct host, so the
>   browser should display a dialogue
>   asking if you want to accept the
>   certificate or not. For example: 1)
>   The server's name "www.example.com"
>   does not match the certificate's name
>   "JMeter Proxy". Somebody may be trying
>   to eavesdrop on you. 2) The
>   certificate for "JMeter Proxy" is
>   signed by the unknown Certificate
>   Authority "JMeter Proxy". It is not
>   possible to verify that this is a
>   valid certificate. You will need to
>   accept the certificate in order to
>   allow the JMeter Proxy to intercept
>   the SSL traffic in order to record it.
>   You should only accept the certificate
>   temporarily.

Also see here http://osdir.com/ml/jmeter-dev.jakarta.apache.org/2009-08/msg00005.html

Answer (score 0):

You  may have to create the certificate for Jmeter.  Below is a fantastic article detailing how to do it:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210

Answer (score 0):

Install [Jmeter Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi) which records HTTPS protocol without any issue.

Comment: what about the certificate? Problem is about certificates not recording. I am still getting this error.