# JMeter https proxy recording not working

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, proxy, jmeter, load-testing

I am recording a https session of a JSF based web app on JMeter and it's not working.

**Target application is hosted on:** AWS
**JMeter version:** 2.9 r1437961
**Browser:** Chrome version 29.0.1547.65
**Java:** java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
**OS:** Ubuntu 12.04

**Proxy server config:**
Port: 8084
Target Controller: Test Plan > Thread Group
Capture HTTP headers is checked.
HTTP Sample settings:
Type: not selected. Follow Redirects and Use KeepAlive checked.

URL patterns to exclude:
1. Added Suggested Excludes
2. .*\.jsf

Exceptions that are getting thrown (from JMeter.log):

```
ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy:  java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1377)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:62)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.writeToClient(Proxy.java:404)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:218)

ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: Problem with SSL certificate? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Connection closed by remote host java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1377)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:62)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.writeToClient(Proxy.java:404)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:218)
```

The steps I am following are:
1. Set proxy server pointing to 8084.
2. Change proxy settings from chrome:
    Set https proxy to 8084.
3. Disabled all chrome extensions and chrome account.
4. Started jmeter proxy server and hit `https://url/login`
5. Certificate confirmation page appears on browser. Meanwhile, jmeter.log shows:

```
   2013/09/11 13:16:30 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8084 
2013/09/11 13:16:30 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Daemon: Proxy up and running! 
2013/09/11 13:22:39 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: Proxy will remove the headers: If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match,Host 
2013/09/11 13:22:39 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: Opened Keystore file: /home/abhijeet/Automation_Dev/LoadAutomation/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.9/bin/proxyserver.jks 
2013/09/11 13:22:39 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host in map (clients4.google.com) 
2013/09/11 13:22:39 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: Opened Keystore file: /home/abhijeet/Automation_Dev/LoadAutomation/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.9/bin/proxyserver.jks 
2013/09/11 13:22:39 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host in map (translate.googleapis.com) 
2013/09/11 13:22:40 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = abhijeet-desktop 
2013/09/11 13:22:40 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 1 
2013/09/11 13:22:40 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll scheme 
2013/09/11 13:22:40 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.FormCharSetFinder: Using htmlparser version: 2.0 (Release Build Sep 17, 2006)<br>
```

6. Thread group starts showing unknown requests to these domains:

> ```
> 1. translate.googleapis.com
> 2. clients4.google.com
> 3. www.google.co.in
> 4. www.google.com
> 5. ssl.gstatic.com
> 6. safebrowsing.google.com
> 7. alt1-safebrowsing.google.com
> 8. clients4.google.com
> 9. www.gstatic.com
> .
> .
> n all other requests going to the target application.
> ```

(For every request the above exceptions are thrown)

I believe, the google domain requests above are getting recorded because chrome is dynamically searching the keywords on google, while I am typing the url string in the address bar. But I don't want these requests to get recorded in the Thread Group.

Also, I tried the solutions from these pages but they didn't work for me:
[Link 1](http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/jmeter-101-using-http-proxy-to-record-your-test/)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384714/problem-with-jmeter-and-http-proxy-server-with-ssl)
[Link 3](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/https-recording-with-new-jmeter_22.html)

I don't understand, why is JMeter not able to use the fake certificate that it already has. I checked the SSL settings in chrome and I could not find any JMeter certificates. Need help!!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and solve it to trust the certificate. Just like you when i look at the

```
Options > Advanced > Certificates > View Certificates ==> Authorities
```

and couldn't see a name ***ApacheJMeterRootCertificate.crt*** or a related name, but i realize that there is a name something like

> _DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate

I click this object and 'Edit_Trust' both item under this object. I share my screenshot. I hope this can be help you and others.

I use Firefox. At chrome there should be similar way to edit the certificate.

[image]

Comment: Its worked!! Thanks man!! Firefox 50.1.0 and Jmeter 3.0 r1743807

Answer (score 2):

To do it in chrome/IE we have to place the certificate into 'Trusted Root Certificates Store'

- Double click the certificate created
- Certificate Import Wizard opens
- Click Next
- Select Second radio button (Place All Certificates in the following store)
- Click Browse and select 'Trusted Root Certificates Authorities'. Click Next
- Click Finish

Check your certificate installed in Chrome Settings (under Http/SSL) - Manage certificates.. (Trusted Root Certificates Authorities Tab)

This should at cure the exceptions thrown as your screenshot shows.

Answer (score 0):

jmeter 2.12 has good support for HTTPS. Under the WorkBench, just select Add -> Non-Test Elements -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. This version worked first time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of Google Chrome made difficult to bypass security settings to avoid security Threats as Phishing or Man-in-the-middle attacks.

I have successfully configured Google Chrome (v.54.0) to allow JMeter Self-Signed Certificate for HTTP(S) Recording.

Here the instructions (on Windows):

1. Open MMC console (SUPER + R, Type mmc, Press Enter)
2. Select File Add/Remove Snap-in
3. Select Certificates Snap-in for Current User
4. Select Trusted Root Certification Authorities >> Certificates
5. Right-click over Certificates folder and select All Tasks >> Import...
6. Import JMeter Self-Signed certificate using the wizard keeping the default  options.
7. Once installed, right-click over JMeter Self-Signed certificate and select Properties
8. On General tab, make sure Enable for all purposes option is selected
9. On Cross-Certificates, include the URL of the application you want to record (make sure you enter the full url, e.g. https://www.live.com)
10. Close all windows.
11. Done. You should now be able to reach the destination bypassing Chrome security alert and start recording.