# Proxy configuration in JMETER is not working for Chrome

Tags: jmeter

Proxy configuration in JMETER is not working for Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64 bit).
I did import of JMETER certificate through MMC console and added my applications URL to Cross-Certificate tab as well.

It gives error -  Your connection is not private. Attackers might be trying to steal your information from "application URL" NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED

Please help to resolve this.

Regards.
Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean by MMC console, as per **Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording** chapter of the JMeter documentation on the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

> **Installing the certificate in Chrome or Internet Explorer**
>
> Both Chrome and Internet Explorer use the same trust store for certificates.
>
> - Browse to the JMeter launch directory, and click on the file ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt, and open it
> - Click on the "Details" tab and check that the certificate details agree with the ones displayed by the JMeter Test Script Recorder
> - If OK, go back to the "General" tab, and click on "Install Certificate …" and follow the Wizard prompts

---

Also given you use Chrome you can consider an alternative way of recording a JMeter test, there is [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), if you switch to it you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.

Comment: I've configured JMeter certificate using MMC (Microsoft Management Console (MMC) is an application that provides a graphical-user interface as per guidelines in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737564/jmeter-https-proxy-recording-not-working

Comment: I can't use JMeter chrome extension (Blazemeter) since i didn't get its offline solution. I need to run load tests on development system which is not internet connected.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved after installation of certificate procedure given by Dmitri T above. 
I was doing same thing but without removing existing certificates.
I should have removed existing and then installed. 
After installation of certificate its better to reopen it and verify its installation status that its not in uninstalled state.
Select JAVA in 'HTTP sampler settings' Type.

Answer (score -1):

Please check with another browser to see if you get the same message, it not, clear your browser's data and try again.